# How do I use a custom version of the apache beam python SDK on DataFlow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

Current version of Apache Beam does not support type code 11 (json) from google spanner, as it uses a version of google-cloud-spanner that is two major versions behind the current release. Therefore I updated my own version to do so - haven't quite figured out how to do a proper PR on the Github or run tests yet.

Either way, that will take a while. I have heard that there is a way to specify a custom Apache beam SDK on DataFlow, but that was from 3 years ago and not specific. Is it still possible? What kind of file do I need to save the SDK in - zip, tar, tar.gz? What folders need to be in that archive? apache_beam, apache_beam-2.34.0.dist-info? just the files in apache_beam? Do I just set the option in sdk-location="gs://bucket" in PipelineOptions?

Thanks.

Comment: it appears that setting sdk-location="gs://bucket" does *something*, as I get this error. I think it can't actually access the bucket, which is.. odd.

WARNING:apache_beam.utils.retry:Retry with exponential backoff: waiting for 19.796091281056984 seconds before retrying _download_file because we caught exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: What if you can use a custom container for Dataflow workers? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers

Comment: It might be good to file an issue in the [Apache Beam](https://github.com/apache/beam) repo asking the maintainers to update the python spanner dependency since it's two major versions behind.

Did you run into any issues when you did the upgrade yourself?

Comment: I did. I also sent an email to dev@apache.org. No response. 

I did, but it only took two changes to fix. I didn't run the test suite, though. I need access to the community so I can do the PR properly and get the setup right without spending days on it.

Answer (score 2):

After you have your container built, you need to ensure that you are using runner V2 and you also need to set the `sdk_container_image` flag like so (the other flags are relevant to `wordcount` and may not be relevant to your pipeline):

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount \
  --input=INPUT_FILE \
  --output=OUTPUT_FILE \
  --project=PROJECT_ID \
  --region=REGION \
  --temp_location=TEMP_LOCATION \
  --runner=DataflowRunner \
  --disk_size_gb=DISK_SIZE_GB \
  --experiments=use_runner_v2 \
  --sdk_container_image=$IMAGE_URI
```

Before you run your pipeline on Dataflow, you should ensure that your container works by running a small job locally like so:

```
python path/to/my/pipeline.py \
  --runner=PortableRunner \
  --job_endpoint=embed \
  --environment_type=DOCKER \
  --environment_config=IMAGE_URI \
  --input=INPUT_FILE \
  --output=OUTPUT_FILE
```

Please take a look at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers for more details.